# Blender Portable 3.2 doesn't look for preferences in the installation directory

Tags: customization

When I was using Blender 3.1, my preferences were stored in C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\config, which is where they should be for a portable version of Blender.

[image]

When I upgraded Blender to 3.2, I copied the config folder from ...\Blender\3.1 to ...\Blender\3.2, but I cannot Blender refuses to look there for the preferences.

Instead, Blender insists upon looking in %appdata%\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2, even though that directory doesn't exist at all.

[image]

How do I get Blender 3.2 to go back to looking where my config info is actually stored?

Comment: It's normal behavior that *portable* program versions stored their data in the user's home directory where they have write permissions. Are you sure 3.1 was a portable version? I wonder why it looks in *C:\program files* for the preferences because usually the installed version also stores the preferences in the user's home directory.

Comment: I guess I'm confused then. Which version of blender keeps the user prefs in the install directory? Because I just tried the installer version, and that one doesn't find my prefs either.